# Can react-native-web also send push notification through the web to a user smartphone like a native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, push-notification

I am working on a react-native application and my target are iOS/Android and the web (with react-native-web).

I'd like to know if there is some sort of "Push Notification" API that I can use for the progressive web application ?

Comment: Did you realize what kind of question you are doing? What kind of "Push Notification" should have a web browser? But the real question is: why this question is not yet downvoted?

Comment: Please explain. Sorry if you felt I was a bit rough but the question was serious. I have a Samsung galaxy S9 and I do receive some notifications from some websites. I think they exists but they might serve a different purpose.  Why would it deserve to be down voted? Downvote are ok as long as they have a cause and a descriptive reason.